# Python Indentation error

Tags: django

I have created a project called class , and an application called students
when I write views, 
I have to use

```
items = class.objects.all()
```

which is giving me error :(
please tell me way to overcome the error without changing my project name..

Thanks :)

Comment: "please tell me way to overcome the error without changing my project name"  Funny.  You cannot use Python reserved words.  "class" is reserved.  You cannot use it.  Rename your project.  Don't ask for miracles that don't exist.

Comment: Your model class should have a capitalized name anyway (PEP8).

Comment: lol ,I changed the project name to school :P , please excuse me as I am still learner ( 2nd day of using django ) but, I expect django to give error while creating the project itself, I get it when I create a project called test ..

Comment: na: "I expect django to give error".  "2nd day of using django  ".  Please don't depend on your expectations.  With no experience, having expectations is a bad habit.  After you get more experience, you'll learn that -- as I said -- You cannot use Python reserved words.  That is the fact of life.  Expectations are a problem, try to live without them.  Just read the documentation for Python and Django carefully and treat it as being all new to you.  Because it is.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to rename it. 'class' is a keyword in python.

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords